# Linux Mint Stuck at "nm-dispatcher.action: Disconnected from the system bus, exiting." when shutting down

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linuxmint

As the title implies, whenever I try and shutdown my Linux Mint Aspire-ES1-111M 3.13.0-37-generic laptop it hangs at "nm-dispatcher.action: Disconnected from the system bus, exiting."  I never get the "[OK]" on the right side, so I'm guessing that whatever this is doing, is not completing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me a little more info on what this is actually doing when it gets to this shutdown task?  I've Googled and can only find this link, which did not help my situation

https://askubuntu.com/questions/87576/slow-shutdown-due-to-modemmanager-and-nm-dispatcher-action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone was wondering how I was able to fix this.  I initially couldn't get anything to boot with the BIOS boot option set to Secure Boot (UEFI), so I switched to Legacy boot.  After following the below video, I was able to get UEFI setup and in turn, it fixed these issues.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iD3JtoSbfOo